# vaadin 8 styles.scss not working with setStyleName

Tags: java, notifications, vaadin, vaadin8

I am working on styles.scss.
This is working :

```
.v-Notification-notif {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        border: 10px solid rgb(245, 121, 0);
}
```

but this is not :

```
.v-Notification-notif.warning .v-Notification-caption {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        font-size: 30px;
}
```

when I say

```
        notif.setStyleName("notif");
```

notif is a Notification. Thank you for help.

I also tried :

```
.notif {
    
    .v-Notification {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        border: 10px solid rgb(245, 121, 0);
    }
    
    .v-Notification.warning .v-Notification-caption {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}
```

but it still does not work.

Comment: Have you used the inspector to look at the dom structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Notification` class is internally using the style name mechanism for the different notification types. `Type.WARNING` is thus only a shorthand for doing `setStyleName("warning")` and `setDelayMsec(1500)`. If you do `setStyleName("notif")` for a warning notification, then you will override the initially set `warning` style name. If you want to use custom styles for some warning notifications, then you can use a distinct style name for them, e.g. `notif-warning`.

Comment: I guess when you say dialog you mean `Notification`? How would scss look like for `notif-warning` ?

Comment: Oops. Fixed the dialog -> notification typo. The main CSS selector would be `.v-Notification-notif-warning`. I'm unfortunately not proficient enough with scss to have a direct answer for the syntax, but I have a faint memory that there might be a mixin that you inherit into the selector if you want to extend the existing warning styles.

Comment: Only problem I still have is `v-Notification-caption` . it does not get detected . I try also changing to `v-Notification-notif-warning-caption` .

Comment: I guess you want to target `.v-Notification-caption` inside `.v-Notification-notif-warning`, so the combined selector would be `.v-Notification-notif-warning .v-Notification-caption`.

Comment: `.v-Notification-notif-warning.warning .v-Notification-caption {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        font-size: 30px;
}`
this does not detect font size

Comment: The main notification element will not have a `warning` style name since that gets replaced by `setStyleName("notif-warning")`. You need to remove `.warning` from the end of the first half of your selector.